# Install Xcode 8 Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Can I know the minimum system requirements to install Xcode 8 beta please.

At the moment I've got OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5

Hardware

- Processor: 2.6 GHz intel core i5
- Memory 8GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Compatibility**

> Xcode 8 beta requires a Mac running macOS El Capitan version 10.11.4 or later. **It includes SDKs for iOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, macOS Sierra version 10.12, and tvOS 10.0**.

you can get the more information see [apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/introduction.html)

for related to your question Hardware is enough , you need to upgrade the Mac OSX ver from `Yosemite version 10.10.5` to `El Capitan version 10.11.4`